# admob video ad not starting

Tags: android, video, admob, ads

I have Just Created Admob Account few Hours ago, I am Testing Video/Award Ad in my phone by following Code , I have created ad unit already for admob reward ad,I am not about this unexpected behavior here is my code , help  would be appreciated

```html
package adwdaw.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-4880509866746816~7547864871");

        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();



    }


    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
                reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Reward the user.
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        loadRewardedVideoAd();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoCompleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Layout Xml File Just Contains Hello-world Text-view Inside Linear Layout

and here is Logcat

```html
07-26 03:26:05.099 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 63c06b2, I8366cd0437
                                                            Build Date                       : 12/06/15
                                                            OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.05.13.02
                                                            Local Branch                     : mybranch17112971
                                                            Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF64.1.2.9_v2
                                                            Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                            Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
07-26 03:26:05.153 6649-6748/adwdaw.myapplication W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
07-26 03:26:05.160 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/cr_DRP: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
07-26 03:26:05.199 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
07-26 03:26:05.211 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
07-26 03:26:05.213 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
07-26 03:26:05.255 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
07-26 03:26:05.291 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.ChimeraRewardedVideoAdCreatorImpl
07-26 03:26:05.306 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
07-26 03:26:05.335 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
07-26 03:26:05.350 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-26 03:26:05.351 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("E66E2B3E4AD74FC9B47856D42F96894D") to get test ads on this device.
07-26 03:26:05.354 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
07-26 03:26:05.377 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
07-26 03:26:05.390 6649-6727/adwdaw.myapplication W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
07-26 03:26:05.390 6649-6727/adwdaw.myapplication W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
07-26 03:26:05.401 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
07-26 03:26:05.412 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
07-26 03:26:05.419 6649-6786/adwdaw.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-26 03:26:05.433 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
07-26 03:26:05.439 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ape
07-26 03:26:05.441 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ffmpeg
07-26 03:26:05.443 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/dts
07-26 03:26:05.450 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
07-26 03:26:05.452 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/vnd.rn-realaudio
07-26 03:26:05.453 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
07-26 03:26:05.454 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
07-26 03:26:05.460 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-flv
07-26 03:26:05.464 6649-6731/adwdaw.myapplication W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
07-26 03:26:05.471 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vnd.rn-realvideo
07-26 03:26:05.473 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vc1
07-26 03:26:05.475 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/ffmpeg
07-26 03:26:05.478 6649-6764/adwdaw.myapplication W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
07-26 03:26:05.490 6649-6786/adwdaw.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-26 03:26:05.553 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
07-26 03:26:05.596 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 6649
07-26 03:26:05.597 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
07-26 03:26:05.932 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/Ads: Server parameters: {"campaign_id":"1057492276","gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544\/5224354917\/cak=no_cache&cadc=sf&caqid=9vFYW8qAGpWVrQGwwZ3gBQ"}
07-26 03:26:05.933 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/Ads: Server parameters: {"campaign_id":"1057492276","gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544\/5224354917\/cak=no_cache&cadc=sf&caqid=9vFYW8qAGpWVrQGwwZ3gBQ"}
07-26 03:26:05.951 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
07-26 03:26:05.958 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/Ads: Starting ad request.
07-26 03:26:05.958 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("E66E2B3E4AD74FC9B47856D42F96894D") to get test ads on this device.
07-26 03:26:05.960 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
07-26 03:26:05.997 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
07-26 03:26:05.999 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
07-26 03:26:06.000 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
07-26 03:26:06.020 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
07-26 03:26:06.113 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 6649
07-26 03:26:06.114 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
07-26 03:26:08.023 6649-6649/adwdaw.myapplication I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init 1.3.1
07-26 03:26:08.312 6649-6857/adwdaw.myapplication I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
07-26 03:26:08.490 6649-6731/adwdaw.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
07-26 03:26:08.554 6649-6786/adwdaw.myapplication V/RenderScript: 0x7f4c0cd000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check everything of this steps: [https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=es#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk)

Mainly Manifest file, and your app-Admob-id and adUnitID